# What is a dense point?

Tags: general-topology

A dense point is apparently a point in a topology that is contained in every nonempty open set. (Context: {0} is a dense point in Spec$\mathbb{Z}$.) But does this have anything to do with dense sets? Dense sets are certainly not contained in every nonempty open set...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a point $p$ is dense iff $\{p\}$ is a dense subset of $X$.

(recall that $D$ is dense in $X$ iff $\overline{D}=X$ iff for all non-empty open sets $O$ of $X$, $O \cap D \neq \emptyset$, and note that $\{p\} \cap O \neq \emptyset$ iff $ p \in O$)

Answer (score 1):

A point $x$ is a dense point iff the singleton set $\{x\}$ is a dense set.